# HLSL mipmapping not working

Tags: 3d, hlsl, level-of-detail

I want to implement a mipmap filter in my 3D game, so that textures which are located far away are using a lower resolution than the original.
For the shader I'm using hlsl version 4_0_level_9_1 or 4_0 depends on which one I will get this running.
I have tried this:

```
texture Texture;
sampler diffuseSampler = sampler_state
{
    Texture = (Texture);
    MAGFILTER = ANISOTROPIC;
    MINFILTER = ANISOTROPIC;
    MIPFILTER = ANISOTROPIC;
    AddressU = Wrap;
    AddressV = Wrap;
};
[...]
Color PixelShaderFunctionTex(VertexShaderOutputTex input)
{
    return tex2Dlod(diffuseSampler, float4(input.TexCoord, 0.0, 0.0));
}
```

in vs_4_0 it still uses the full-res texture.
And in vs_4_0_level_9_1 it won't even compile: "texlod not supported on this target"

I could manually generate the downscaled textures, but there must be a way to only input one texture and let hlsl do the rest.

In short:
How to apply the mipmap filter in hlsl?

Comment: ``tex2dlod`` is for accessing a specific level of the mipmap chain. You just use standard ``tex2d`` with the correct texture state objects set and you'll get mipmap filtering. As noted below, the sampler state you define in HLSL is not relevant to the ``vs`` profiles only ``fx``.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't.

Unfortunately some online resources don't make this explicit, but the code you've given is actually not HLSL; instead it's part of the old (and deprecated) effects framework.  What actually happens if you use the effects framework (which is nothing more than a wrapper around the D3D API) is that a shader object and a state object will be created and set for the current draw call.

In the absence of the effects framework (which I assume because you actually have to intentionally set out to use it these days) you need to create your own sampler state object and set it.

Comment: See [this post](https://fx11.codeplex.com/discussions/450240) for some more background here.

Answer (score 1):

That there is DX9 HLSL

You want something like this:

```
Texture2D Texture : register(t0);;
sampler diffuseSampler : register(s0);

struct VertexShaderOutput
{
float4 Position : SV_Position;
float2 TexCoord : TEXCOORD0;

};
// outputs a full screen triangle with screen-space coordinates
// input: three empty vertices
VertexShaderOutput VSQuad( uint vertexID : SV_VertexID )
{
VertexShaderOutput result;
result.TexCoord = float2((vertexID << 1) & 2, vertexID & 2);
result.Position  = float4(result.TexCoord  * float2(2.0f, -2.0f) + float2(-1.0f, 1.0f), 0.0f, 1.0f);
return result;
}

float4 PixelShaderFunctionTex(VertexShaderOutput input) :SV_Target0
{
// float3(UV,Mip)
float4 color = Texture.SampleLevel(diffuseSampler, float3(input.TexCoord, 0.0f));

return color;
}
```

then like Le Comte du Merde-fou said, set all state by hand.

like this:

```
  _Context.XXXXShader.SetSampler(0, yourSampler)
  _Context.XXXXShader.SetShaderResource(0, yourSRV)
```

ps. that's sm 5.0 but I think sm 4.0- m 5.0 is close if not the same and you wont need the vertex shader, that's just a bonus incase u want a cool way of doing full screen quads too.